# Unitary operators and observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

Is every unitary operator an observable? Is every observable a unitary operator? Why aren't they the same?

They seem to be the same.

Comment: Very few unitary operators are observables. Do you mean Hermitain operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observables are operators with real eigenvalues. Unitary operators do not necessarily have real eigenvalues (the only real eigenvalues a unitary operator can have are -1 and 1) so the straight forward answer to your question is trivially no.

If you meant to say "Hermitian Operator" instead of "Unitary Operator" then for the most part all observables are Hermitian, but of course not all Hermitian Operators are observables; namely because they don't correspond to a real attribute of a system, and more generally for an operator to be an observable it must be bounded when acting on a state; not all Hermitian operators acting on a space $H$ are bounded. This is not the main point however, since there even exist Bounded Hermitian Operators that don't correspond to observables (remember this is Physics not Math, for something to be an "Observable" it must actually represent something meaningful about the real world).

In the first phrase of the last paragraph I said "for the most part" and that is because in standard textbooks it is stated that all observables are Hermitian, but that is not generally the case; this paper outlines it quite well https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04287.pdf . Non-Hermitian Observables are something I have never actually dealt with but the paper is interesting none the less.